# Getting a "list" of Viewable Records in Mongo

Tags: mongodb

Let's say I have a person's table and I want the id, name, and age of every person that is over the age of 30.

In SQL (via SQL Management Studio) I would do something like:

```
SELECT Id, Name, Age
FROM Persons
WHERE Age > 30;
```

And I get a nice list that I can copy and paste to excel. In MongoDb, even if I ask for particular fields to be returned, I still get a bunch of distinct results that I have to click on individually to view (at least in RoboMongo). How do I get a list like the one in excel to glance through?

Do I have to iterate through the returned records and print? Or are there better options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get results in csv, you can use mongoexport command line utility.

```
mongoexport -d test -c records 
            -q '{ a: { $gte: 3 } }'   
            --type=csv --fields name,address   
            --out /opt/backups/contacts.csv
```

where:

- -d database
- -c collection
- -q query
- --fields -> specify fields to export
- --out file name

[more here](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/program/mongoexport/)

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed.